# How to check that a string is a string literal for mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

With this code

```py
import os
from typing import Literal, get_args

Markets = Literal[
    "BE", "DE", "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "SE"
]
MARKETS: list[Markets] = list(get_args(Markets))


def foo(x: Markets) -> None:
    print(x)


market = os.environ.get("market")


if market not in MARKETS:
    raise ValueError


foo(market)
```

I get the following error.

```
Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Literal['BE', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'IT', 'LT', 'LV', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'SE']"  [arg-type]mypy(error)
```

How do I need to check the `market` variable so that `mypy` knows that is of correct type?

Comment: Just found out that I can use `cast` from the `typing` module. Is that the correct way to fix it?

`market = cast(Markets, market)`

Comment: ```if not isinstance(market, Markets):
    raise ValueError```

Comment: That does not solve it for me. Then I get 

`Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "Union[type, UnionType, Tuple[Union[type, UnionType, Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]"  [arg-type]mypy(error)`
and 
`Argument 1 to "foo" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "Literal['BE', 'DE', 'DK', 'EE', 'ES', 'FI', 'FR', 'GB', 'IT', 'LT', 'LV', 'NL', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'SE']"  [arg-type]mypy(error)`

Comment: `Literal` is intended to match *literal* strings, not define subtypes based on a finite set of values. `mypy`, for instance, will not accept `a = "BE"; x: list[Markets] = [a]` because `a` is a variable, not a literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Alternative: Custom [`TypeGuard`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeGuard)

Since Python `3.10` you can define your own type guards, which can make this slightly more elegant:

```py
import os
from typing import Literal, TypeGuard, get_args


MarketT = Literal[
    "BE", "DE", "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "SE"
]
MARKETS: list[MarketT] = list(get_args(MarketT))


def is_valid_market(val: str) -> TypeGuard[MarketT]:
    return val in MARKETS


def foo(x: MarketT) -> None:
    print(x)


market = os.environ.get("market", "")
reveal_type(market)
assert is_valid_market(market)
reveal_type(market)

foo(market)
```

Running `mypy` over this will show you that before the `assert` the type is inferred as `str`, whereas after the assert it is narrowed to that union of string literals you defined earlier. This basically combines both the runtime check (that you already had) and the static narrowing into one.

Note: I still need to provide a `str` instance as the default for `os.environ.get` because otherwise `market` might still turn out to be `None`. We could instead annotate the `val` parameter in `is_valid_market` with `Optional[str]` to avoid another type checker error. This is just a matter of preference.

---

### Original post

Yes, [`cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) is the easiest way IMO:

```py
import os
from typing import Literal, cast, get_args


Market = Literal[
    "BE", "DE", "DK", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "IT", "LT", "LV", "NL", "NO", "PL", "PT", "SE"
]
MARKETS: list[Market] = list(get_args(Market))


def foo(x: Market) -> None:
    print(x)


market = cast(Market, os.environ.get("market"))
# reveal_type(market)

if market not in MARKETS:
    raise ValueError

foo(market)
```

Uncommenting the `reveal_type` statement and running `mypy` will give you the following:

`note: Revealed type is "Union[Literal['BE'], Literal['DE'], Literal['DK'], Literal['EE'], Literal['ES'], Literal['FI'], Literal['FR'], Literal['GB'], Literal['IT'], Literal['LT'], Literal['LV'], Literal['NL'], Literal['NO'], Literal['PL'], Literal['PT'], Literal['SE']]"`

So the type is correctly inferred as a union of those string literals.

As a side note, semantically, I would say the name of your literal union should be `Market`, not `Markets` (maybe even `MarketType` or `MarketT`). It refers to the type of the variable that will represent a single market after all, not multiple. The `list` name on the other hand is fitting, since it refers to a collection of *all* the possible markets.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I agree about the semantics, I will rename it to MarketT.

Comment: @Prokie I just thought of an alternative that may be even better, depending on personal preferences. I added it to the top of my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I also like that solution, but it is hard to find a preference. But I think I will use the one with TypeGuard.

Comment: Just came across this... TypeGuard is pretty neat

Answer (score -2):

No need to use `cast(..)`. Just type your variable:

```py
def foo(x: Market) -> None:
    print(x)

market: Market = os.environ.get("market")

foo(market)
```

Comment: Have you actually checked this with `mypy`? `os.environ.get` has the return type `Optional[str]`. Meaning you'll rightfully get an `[assignment]` error telling you that the variable is declared to be that union of literals, whereas the expression is a union of _any_ `str` and `None`.

Comment: You just move the error from one statement to an other.